CP-SAT how to make constrain based on start var range
BoolVar across1 = model.NewBoolVar("across1");
BoolVar across2 = model.NewBoolVar("across2");
model.Add(end >= endOfWork).OnlyEnforceIf(across1);
model.Add(end < endOfWork).OnlyEnforceIf(across1.Not());
model.Add(end <= nextDayStart).OnlyEnforceIf(across2);
model.Add(end > nextDayStart).OnlyEnforceIf(across2.Not());
model.Add(duration == task.duration + 960).OnlyEnforceIf(new ILiteral[] { across1, across2 });
this OnlyEnforceIf looks like it is not using AND operator between the vars?
I expect if both bool vars are true, the duration to be increased by 960 minutes

Where is duration used? Please provide a stand alone code that exhibits the issue.
